# Can I use a 12 V solenoid valve directly connected with a 12 V battery?

Tags: solenoid

Can I connect a 12V solenoid valve directly to a 12V battery?

Comment: Is it an AC solenoid valve?

Comment: What is the point? If the valve is always on, you might as well just use a manual valve.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you might want to connect a reverse biased diode across it to allow the current through the coil a path to flow when the battery is disconnected, else you can generate some very high voltages (and sparks!) on disconnection.

typical circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faPStg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: How can I get diode for this diagram? I mean which type of diode.

Comment: DC solenoid valve.

Comment: It needs a current rating to match the current rating of your solenoid valve, and more than 12V reverse voltage - IN4001 is a typical choice for small solenoids, and is capable of up to 30A peak current.

Comment: I can't understand clearly.can u explain me more details.

Comment: If your solenoid draws 1 Amp when operating, then you need a diode that is rated for 1 Amp current - and an IN4001 would be a good choice.  If it draws 100 A, you need a different diode, the relevant parts of the diode data sheet that you should check are the reverse voltage capability (the IN4001 is OK up to 50V), and the current handling - the IN4001 can handle 1A continuously, and up to 30A for a short period (such as when a solenoid is deactivated)

Comment: Might want a fuse, too. Practically speaking. Batteries can make a right mess of unfused circuits. Put it as near the battery as possible to cover as many errors/problems/defects in wiring as possible.

Comment: It would be sensible to check if the solinoid is continiously rated.Some are not so check your application to avoid the possibility of burnout .